# Linking the sources of a java project into another

Tags: intellij-idea

I've tried to link the sources of a Java project in Intellij Idea 11.1.2 into another, as it is possible to do in Eclipse IDE. But I haven't found this feature yet : is Intellij Idea missing such a feature ? If no, what is the menu ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify the question, do you mean modules? See http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/migration_faq.html.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) So, yes I meant an intellij idea module (That is in fact, Eclipse project equivalent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [configure dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html) between modules, so just add one module into the dependencies of another.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I've added the other project iml as a dependency, then I was able to do the right imports